# Test-SPContentDatabase doesn't return information

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, powershell

I run Test-SPContentDatabase like this:

```
  public string Test_Associate(string DbName,string UrlApp) {


        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

        // open it
        runspace.Open();

        using (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            powerShell.Runspace = runspace;

            powerShell.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("DbName", DbName);
            powerShell.AddScript("$DbName");

            powerShell.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("urlApp", UrlApp);
            powerShell.AddScript("$urlApp");

            powerShell.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy").AddArgument("Unrestricted");
            powerShell.AddScript(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @".\Data_tier\PS1\Test_Association.ps1");

            Collection<PSObject> results = powerShell.Invoke();

            // convert the script result into a single string
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (PSObject obj in results)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
            }
            runspace.Close();
            return stringBuilder.ToString();

        }
    }
```

My ps1 file:

```
    if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) 
{
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}
Test-SPContentDatabase -Name $DbName -WebApplication $urlApp
```

But the result doesn't returns a list of issues.
it return : "Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseTestResult" .
how can I get the list of issues.
best reagards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
Test-SPContentDatabase -Name $DbName -WebApplication $urlApp > C:\\TextResults.txt
```

or

```
Test-SPContentDatabase -Name $DbName -WebApplication $urlApp > C:\\TextResults.xml
```

it should create a result file in C drive.

**Edit**

Right way,

```
Test-SPContentDatabase -Name $DbName -WebApplication $urlApp | Out-File c:\TestResult.txt
```

Seems like `>>` opens and closes file for each line, however `Out-File` just opens and closes the file just once as stated in this [post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/gbordier/archive/2009/05/05/powershell-and-writing-files-how-fast-can-you-write-to-a-file.aspx).

Comment: A more PowerShell'is what of doing this would be to use `Test-SPContentDatabase -Name $DbName -WebApplication $urlApp | Out-File c:\TestResult.txt`

Comment: @AndersRask Ta, you are right, http://blogs.technet.com/b/gbordier/archive/2009/05/05/powershell-and-writing-files-how-fast-can-you-write-to-a-file.aspx